# Conexión ODBC con usuario y contraseña de tablas vinculadas

Tags: vba

Usando ACCESS 2016 32 bits y SQL Server 2019 tengo la siguiente rutina

```
Dim tdf As dao.TableDef
Dim cadena As String
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim con As String

Set db = CurrentDb
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If InStr(tdf.Connect, "ODBC;") <> 0 Then
        con = "ODBC;driver=SQL Server;server=miservidor;database=middbb;" _
            & "UID=miusuario;PWD=micontraseña;"
        tdf.Connect = con
        tdf.RefreshLink
        db.QueryDefs.Refresh
    End If

Next tdf
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

si la ejecuto puedo sin problemas ver las tablas vinculadas pero cuando salgo del access y entro al tratar de verlas me dice que la conexión es desde un dominio que no es de confianza y por lo que veo el usuario y la contraseña no se copian en la propiedad connect, si ejecuto otra vez mi rutina las abro sin problemas. Si por ejemplo creo una consulta de paso a través y le pongo la misma cadena de conexión se ejecuta bien incluso cuando salgo y entro del access. ¿ alguna idea o solución ?. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución en este link https://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/24851-memorise-odbc-username-password-access-db.html. Saludos